# jQuery select all elements end with, not starting with

Tags: jquery, selector

I thought this should select all elements ending with `1000_from` but not those that starts with `rif_`. Where is the error?

```
$('[id$=1000_from]:not[id^=rif_]');
```

**EDIT:**

```
$('[id^=rif_][id$=_from]').on('keyup click change', function(){

    var rif_id = $(this).attr('id').split('_');

    var id = rif_id[1];
    var value = $(this).val();

    $('[id$='+id+'_from]:not([id^=rif_])').val(value);
});
```

It updates also the editing value

HTML:

Get value from:

```
<input type="datetime-local"
       name="rif_<?=$rif['p']?>_from"
       id="rif_<?=$rif['p']?>_from" />
```

Update to (there are many elements ending with `<?=$rif['p']?>_from`:

```
<input type="datetime-local"
       name="<?=$s['nr']?>_<?=$rif['p']?>_from"
       id="<?=$s['nr']?>_<?=$rif['p']?>_from" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put your condition in `:not()`.

Replace `:not[id^=rif_]` with `:not([id^="rif_"])`

```
ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").
```

change id in your input field:

```
<input type="datetime-local"
       name="<?=$s['nr']?>_<?=$rif['p']?>_from"
       id="<?=$s['nr']?>_<?=$rif['p']?>_from" />
```

Try this:

```
$('[id$="1000_from"]:not([id^="rif_"])')
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/r7JYn/)**

Comment: @Perocat: Check updated fiddle. And if still you are facing an issue make [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your html & jquery code.

Comment: Where was the problem? On the `""` or on the `(...)`. When should I use "" with selectors? Thank you!

Comment: @Perocat: Updated with description check bro :)

Comment: I edited my question with a complete example where the solution doesn't work

Comment: @Perocat: can you share your html too?

Comment: Does not work, I changed `id="s_<?=$s['nr']?>_<?=$rif['p']?>_from"` but the problem is still there